# Dash shows a extra chrome icon related to Amazon

Tags: unity, google-chrome, icons, unity-dash

In Dash the Chrome icon shows up twice under applications, one that says "Google Chrome" and a non-functional one that reads Amazon.com:J....-Google chrome. I have tried purging the Chrome app yet the Amazon related icon remains. How do I get rid of it?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked your search setting in System Settings -> Security & Privacy to turn off online search results?

Comment: Yes, I have had that off for many months now. This icon has only appeared and is related to a page in Amazon I had only recently accessed.

Comment: In System Settings -> Security & Privacy under the Files & Application tab did you try the Clear Usage Data... button?

Comment: No, I had not tried that but I just did it to no effect.

Comment: If this is still present, have you tried Right clicking on the icon to see if you can delete or uninstall?

Comment: Tried it, it brings me to a view that shows it has not been reviewed and a launch button which does nothing. No option to delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a file "google-chrome-stable.desktop" that contained the Amazon.com information of the icon. This was in ~/.local/share/applications. Deleting that file removed the icon from Dash and has solved my issue.